# Stuck on "Preparing iPhone for software update"

Tags: iphone, software-update

I'm trying to update my 8+ while connecting to I-tunes.
And now it is  Stuck on "Preparing iPhone for software update" for 2hours.
What sould I do?
Thanx

Comment: Wait as long as possible then restart and try again.  I can't see any other choice.

Answer (score 1):

iTunes is often stuck for no reason. Usually, I would restart iTunes and it works. If that doesn't work, you should reinstall iTunes.

Comment: How is reinstalling going to change anything?

Comment: I'm not an iTunes specialist, so I can just restart iTunes or reinstall it. It works every time. I asked for help from Apple Community. They suggested that too.